# Error Classification Metrics, Can't Handle a Mix of Binary and Continous Targets

Tags: python, classification, confusion-matrix

Hi I am very confused to solve this problem. It's my first time trying deep learning. I have checked any questions and answers from other questions but still not getting any resolution. How to solve this error

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets
```

Here is my Code:

```
In>>y_pred = model.predict(seq_array, batch_size=200, verbose=1)
In>>y_true = label_array
In>>print('Confusion matrix\n- x-axis is true labels.\n- y-axis is predicted labels')
In>>print(y_pred)
In>>print(y_true)
In>>confusion_m = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
In>>confusion_m
Out>>
20/20 [==============================] - 2s 83ms/step
Confusion matrix
- x-axis is true labels.
- y-axis is predicted labels
[[0.00791603]
 [0.00798142]
 [0.00804839]
 ...
 [0.52200854]
 [0.5300765 ]
 [0.53883666]]
[[0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 ...
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
```

Comment: have you tried this? `y_pred = (model.predict_proba(seq_array)[:,1] >= th)` where th is the acceptable threshold

Answer (score 1):

Your `predict()` returns scores/probabilities rather than classes. You should compare those to a threshold of your choice to get class predictions (0 or 1). Something like `confusion_matrix(y_true, (y_pred > 0.5))` should likely work (assuming those are numpy arrays).

Comment: what is that mean with y_pred > 0.5? is it just assumption numpy?

Comment: I assume your `y_pred` and `y_true` are single column numpy arrays (judging by your print() output). `(y_pred > 0.5)` should yield the array of the same length having 1 where the score is above 0.5 and 0 otherwise - that should be compatible with your `y_true`.